# how to choose a different string ? (easier)

Tags: java, string

i have `String cat = "cat1, cat1, cat1, cat1, cat2, cat2, cat2, cat3";`

i need to `String cat = "cat1, cat2, cat3";`

how to do this ?

It's my solution but not excellent:

```
String[] words = cat.split(",");
Arrays.sort(words);
....
```

Comment: Homework? Here are some hints. Split on ",", use `Arrays.asList` on the resulting array. Create a `Set<String>` out of the resulting list to remove dups. Join the resulting strings back into a new string if needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can try this -

```
String cat = "cat1,cat1,cat1,cat1,cat2,cat2,cat2,cat3";
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(cat.split(",")));
```

Comment: This is fine if the cats don't need to be in any particular order.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
String cat = "cat1, cat1, cat1, cat1, cat2, cat2, cat2, cat3";
String text = new TreeSet<String>(Arrays.asList(cat.split(", "))).toString();
String cats = text.substring(1, text.length()-1);
System.out.println(cats);
```

This will produce the String your require.

```
cat1, cat2, cat3
```

Answer (score 1):

here:

```
//hash
HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet<String>();
String[] words = cat.split(",");
for(int i = 0;i < words.length; i++) hs.add(words[i]);

//dehash
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
Iterator it = hs.iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
{
    builder.append(it.next());
    builder.append(",");
}
String dehashed = builder.toString();
```

Comment: Can you link the Javadoc for `HashSetIterator`? Or is this another language?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I could've sworn HashSetIterator existed in Java.. changing it